# Displaying a character count while the user is typing?

Tags: c#, char, richtextbox

I'm trying to build a program with that displays the number of characters and words while a user is typing into the text box. I thought I knew what I was doing but ran into this error:

> 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to
>   'Systems.Windows.Forms.Label'

This is what I have so far. The last line of code contains the error:

```
    private void userTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userInput = userTextBox.Text;
        char charCount;
        charCount = userInput[0];

        charCountOutput = charCount.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: charCountOutput.Text = charCount.ToString();

Comment: why are you looking at the first character of the string to get its length? [userInput.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx).ToString() will work much better.

Comment: Thank you Jim. It's the simple things that always gets me :)

Comment: Yes, Shaun Wilde, that actually does work better. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You need to set the property on the Label to set the text

```
charCountOutput.Text = ...
```

2) The length of a string can be accessed through the [Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

```
charCountOutput.Text = userInput.Length.ToString();
```

Comment: What if I wanted to exclude spaces though?

Comment: perhaps something like `userInput.Replace(" ","").Length.ToString()`

Comment: Or use the [Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.count(v=vs.90).aspx) method e.g. something like `userInput.Count(x => { return !Char.IsWhiteSpace(x); });`

Comment: Nope that didn't work. Thank you for the help though

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2010. It is ok though, Shaun, I figured out how to fix it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
charCountOutput.Text = charCount.ToString();
```

Assuming charCountOutput is the label

Your code is trying to assign the Label object the value of a string, which is a type mismatch (obviously).

Comment: Ha ha ! I knew it was something easy! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning to a textfield, changing the text of the field.

```
charCountOutput.Text = charCount.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     int countChar = userTextBox.Text.ToString().Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a late addition - you probably already have seen this, but here's a really fast approach. Assumes charCountOutput is label on your form:

```
        private void userTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var userInput = userTextBox.Text;
        charCountOutput.Text = userInput.Length.ToString();
    }
```